# Reading and writing arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently trying to use PHP to keep track of the number of "likes" on the pages of my website.  What I'd like to do is put all the info into a single array, instead of a separate file for each page, each one containing a single integer.  What I've tried to do is set up some file (call it data.txt) that contains this array.

```
$array = array(
    "Page1" => 10,
    "Page2" => 3,
);
```

For example, above, Page1 has 10 likes and Page2 has 3.
**Here's the real meat of the question:**  How can I write the above array to a text file, and then read from it later?  Most of the approaches I've tried end with simply reading out a string, which isn't which isn't what I'm looking for (I want to be able to easily access the number of likes directly an array).

Here's the `var_dump` for anyone who was interested:

```
array(2) { ["Page1"]=> int(10) ["Page2"]=> int(3) }
```

Maybe there's some way to parse that back into an array?

Comment: If you have to write an array as text, then `serialize()` it, and `unserialize()` it when you read it; or use `json_encode()` on write and `json_decode()` on read.... but using a database is a far better choice

Comment: true if you can use database will be best choice

Comment: if you want simple way you can use implode and explode

Comment: You could use var_export instead and then include() the file, because it outputs a php-readable format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Mark Baker, you need to serialize the data in order to save it to the file. Later you can read it and deserialize it back to an array. Here is how:

```
<?php

// DISPLAY ARRAY BEFORE SAVING IT.    
$old_array = array( "Page1" => 10,
                    "Page2" => 3,
                  );
echo "OLD ARRAY" .
     "<br/><br/>";
print_r( $old_array );

// WRITE ARRAY TO FILE.
$old_data = serialize( $old_array );
file_put_contents( "my_file.txt",$old_data );

// READ ARRAY FROM FILE.    
$new_data = file_get_contents( "my_file.txt" );
$new_array = unserialize( $new_data );

// DISPLAY ARRAY TO CHECK IF IT'S OK.
echo "<br/><br/>" .
     "NEW ARRAY" .
     "<br/><br/>";
print_r( $new_array );

?>
```

This is what you should see on screen :

```
OLD ARRAY

Array ( [Page1] => 10 [Page2] => 3 )

NEW ARRAY

Array ( [Page1] => 10 [Page2] => 3 )
```

And, if you open "my_file.txt" you will see this:

```
a:2:{s:5:"Page1";i:10;s:5:"Page2";i:3;}
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of simple solution I was looking for.  My school owns the site's server hardware, so I've had difficulty installing MySQL/phpMyAdmin (but those both work on my localhost, so I've got that going for me, which is nice).  Many thanks!